# Cannot select from a datagrid using javascript in Morzilla,IE8

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, mozilla

In  a form(File.aspx)  i am generating another popup window (Lookup.aspx including a DataGrid). From that datagrid i can fill the textbox in File.aspx using javascript.It works in InternetExplorer7 & InternetExplorer8 .But in Morzilla the popup & datagrid is appearing,but i can't select from datagrid .

In same manner a calendar image  onclick="displaycalendar(... );" i can select datetime to a textbox,it works in IE6 and IE7 but doent works in IE8 Morzilla.Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the textbox in Javascript?  Mozilla expects document.getElementById() - IE lets you get way with accessing the textbox name alone.  document.getElementById will work in both browsers.

BTW - are you getting any errors in Mozilla?  Check in Tools -> Error Console.